# if(isset($_POST['login']))

Tags: php, authentication, isset

Sorry for my english, i'm a french student.
I would try to do a PHP login and it doesn't work.. The signin work perfectly and I used the same code as it so that's strange.

Let check out my login.php :

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['login'])) {

        extract($_POST);

        echo "Connexion réussie";

        if(!empty($lpassword) && !empty($lpseudo)) {

            $q = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE pseudo = :pseudo");
            $q->execute(['pseudo' => $lpseudo]);
            $result = $q->fetch();

            if($result == true) {
                $hashpassword = $result['password'];
                if(password_verify($lpassword, $hashpassword)) {
                    echo "Le mdp est bon, connexion en cours";




                } else {
                    echo "Le mot de passe est incorrect";
                }




            } else {
                echo "Le compte portant l'email " . $lmail . "n'existe pas";
            }

        } else {
            echo "Les champs ne sont pas remplis !";
        }

    } else {
        echo "Marche pas";
    }


?>
```

and my page with the form :

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="connexion_style.css" />

<title>To-Ornament - Connexion / Inscription</title>

<body>

    <?php 

    include 'includes/database.php';
    global $db;

    ?>

    <section>



        <form method="post" action="connexion.php">
            <h2>Inscription</h2>

            <label for="pseudo">Pseudo</label> <br>
            <input type="text" name="pseudo" id="pseudo" size="50" maxlength="20" />
            <br>
            <label for="pass">Mot de passe</label> <br>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="50"/>
            <br>
            <label for="conf_pass">Confirmation du mot de passe</label> <br>
            <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" size="50"/>
            <br>
            <label for="email">Adresse mail</label> <br>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" size="50"/>
            <br> <br>
            <a href=""><input class="Inscription" type="submit" value="S'inscrire" name="formsend" id="formsend"></a>
        </form>

    <?php include 'includes/signin.php'; ?>

        <p id="barre"></p>

        <form>
          <h2>Connexion</h2>

          <label for="pseudo">Pseudo</label> <br>
            <input type="text" name="lpseudo" id="lpseudo" maxlength="20" size="50"/>
            <br>
          <label for="pass">Mot de passe</label> <br>
          <input type="password" name="lpassword" id="lpassword" size="50"/>
           <br> <br>
          <a href=""><input class="Connexion" type="submit" name="login" value="Connexion" id="login"></a>
        </form>

    <?php include 'includes/login.php'; ?>

    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

I don't understand how it's possible to work with the signin.php but not with the login.php because the name=login is right dans my "   if(isset($_POST['login']))   " too ..

Please help me quickly !
Ask me more questions if you need

Comment: `I would try to do a PHP login and it doesn't work` what is the output you get?

Comment: by the way - do NOT use `extract` on `$_POST`

Comment: I get no output.

Comment: And I followed a Youtuber that have the same code but him, it works and he used extract($_POST). Should I really change this ?

Comment: are there any messages in the error log?

Comment: nope, no message in the error log

Comment: None in Sublime Text and none in the website page

Comment: I put echos and only the echo "Marche pas" appears

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
          <h2>Connexion</h2>
```

I think you forgot the `method="post" action="login.php"` in your form definition.

And you should not use `extract` for data you can't control. If there is some data in the `$_POST` that you don't await it can override your already defined variables. A simple example:

```
$_POST = [
    'success' => true    
];

$success = false;

extract($_POST);
var_dump($success); // true
```

Comment: Owh yes that's it! I put it for the signin but I forgot it for the login. Thank you so much, i a little bit stupid ^^'

Comment: don't worry. I don't know how often I've searched hours for such erros.